# How to re-enable UITableViewCell content views when Delete button disappears in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Is there any delegate call back or any way to know when, in iOS 7, a UITableViewCell which is in edit mode and have Delete button show up is tapped and Delete button disappears?

I have a text field on my cell which I want to enable/disable based on whether the cell is swiped to show Delete button or tapped again to hide the Delete button.

With iOS 6, layoutSubviews gets called when Delete button disappears but not with iOS 7.

Any clue as to how to handle this in iOS 7.

```
- (id)initWithRequestTypes:(NSArray *)iRequestTypes cellType:(NSString *)iCellType reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)iReuseIdentifier {
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:iReuseIdentifier]) {
    // Doing initialization here
        }

    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    if (self.showingDeleteConfirmation) {
            // Doing some frame adjustments here
    }

    // Cell components adjustments
}


- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)iState {
    [super willTransitionToState:iState];
}
```

Comment: If it's a custom cell class, look at the `willTransitionToState:` method.

Comment: Even willTransitionToState does not get called for iOS7. Its called when tapped on - button initially but not when cell is again tapped to make the Delete button disappear.

Comment: I have custom cells in iOS 7 and it's called for me. Perhaps you should show some of your code.

Comment: Added my code from custom cell which is sub-classing from a generic class which is sub-classing from UITableViewCell. I am getting call back when I tap on - button but when I tap on the cell to make the Delete button disappear, the delegate does not get called.

Comment: Strange. I just verified in my own app. I set a breakpoint in a custom cell's `willTransitionToState:` method. The breakpoint was reached when I did a swipe-to-delete and when I tapped elsewhere to dismiss the Delete confirmation button. I did this test on a device with iOS 7.1.2.

Comment: I am testing with 7.1.2 only and its not working for me.

Comment: I tested this with iOS 8 and observed that when I try to dismiss Delete button on UITableViewCell, layoutSubviews gets called.